# AngularJS: UI Router doesn't load template and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

so I'm trying to uderstand where's the error in my code,
when I access **/dashboard** it just loads the template of the first route **'root'**, which is **SYSTEM_VARS.includes.general.root**
but loads the console.log inside the resolve of state **root.dashboard.home**

I have the ui-view directive added in [index.html](https://gist.github.com/WagnerMoreira/b15f0b677dcb6cd0403d)

Please check my [routes.js](https://gist.github.com/WagnerMoreira/085aa0992dc7355ae61e) file

The console logging the console.logs of the routes:

```
State ROOT: Resolve root
Current State: DASHBOARD
Current State: DASHBOARD.HOME
```

the content of /dashboard state template is just an `<h1>DASHBOARD HOME</h1> for tests`

**Short:** the /dashboard state aren't loading the template and controller
configured.

Comment: Where is your app module/`app.js`. I don't see you declaring your app as an Angular app - you don't have `ng-app="yourApp"` in your `index.html`.

Comment: External code reference links are bad. Please add the code to the question, as is required at SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please be aware that dots inside the state names produce nested states. Every nested state wants to be included in a `ui-view` in the parent state's template.

This seems to be set up correctly between `root.dashboard` and `root.dashboard.home`.

But the template of `root.dashboard` itself is not inserted correctly into your index page because you used an unnamed ui-view in the index page, but configured your state to use a named view called `contentView`. This should be fixed as soon as you remove the `views` property and just define the `template` as `uiView`.  The `root.dashboard` state should look like this:

```
{
    abstract: true,
    url: '/dashboard',
    template: uiView,
    resolve: {
        data: [function () {
             console.warn('Current State: DASHBOARD');
        }]
    }
}
```

For reference, please see: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#example---name-matching

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!! This works and I understand this situation now, thank you!!!!!